# Having trouble restricting editing to the owner of the profile in Django while using a custom user model

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

So, I decided to go with a custom user model so I could customize the registration page and require users to submit a photo during registration. I am not sure if I needed to go through all this just for that, and I am finding out that it's more difficult to manage a custom user class.  Right now, I am attempting to only allow the current logged in user to be able to edit their own info, not anyone else's. I totally know how to do this through the normal User model, but I can't figure out how to do this through the custom user model path. The only way I know how to do this is to create a separate model that has a foreign key to my Profile model, 'owner', and compare the two ID's when the current user try's to edit someone else's profile. I looked around a couple different related questions, and I couldn't come up with a solution either. Best I got was doing 'settings.Auth_User_Model instead of 'User' for owner, but that doesn't work either.

**The error:**

```
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
dating_app.Profile.owner: (fields.E301) Field defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out.
    HINT: Update the relation to point at 'settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL'.
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser,BaseUserManager, User
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):

def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
    if not username:
        raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
    if not description:
        raise ValueError("You must write a description")
    if not photo:
        raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

    user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username = username, 
            description= description,
            photo= photo,

        )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user 


def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
    user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            username=username,
            description=description,
            photo=photo,

        )

    user.is_admin=True
    user.is_staff=True
    user.is_superuser=True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
#what I added
description                 = models.TextField()
photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
owner                       = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


objects = ProfileManager()


def __str__(self):
    return self.username


def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
    return self.is_admin


def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
    return True
```

**Views.py for update_account and owner**

```
def update_account(request, profile_id):
    #Edit an existing profile 
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,id=profile_id)
    update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    check_profile_owner(profile.owner,request.user)

    if request.method != 'POST':
        #Initial request; prefil form with current entry
        update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile)
    else:
        #POST data submitted;process data. 
        update_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
        if update_form.is_valid():
            update_form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('dating_app:profile', args=[profile.id]))

    context = {'profile' : profile, 'update_form' : update_form}
    return render(request, 'dating_app/update.html', context)

"""Checks to see if the current user is also the profile owner"""
def check_profile_owner(user):

     if owner != user:
        raise Http404
```

**settings.py**

```
#For Custom Model 
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'dating_app.Profile'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you did far more work than necessary. Django user models (in various forms depending on if you're using ALLAUTH) include nearly everything you need except for a profile. In my limited experience, the easiest thing to do is to subclass a custom user in a users model:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
   pass
```

While this can be unnecessary if you never add new fields, it allows you better scalability in the future. Then, create a Profile class which has a foreignkey link to your CustomerUser. In that profile, you can put all of those things you'd like...pictures, bio's, preferences, etc.

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    biography = models.TextField(max_length=255, default='', null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics/%Y/%m/%d')
    nativelanguage = models.ManyToManyField(Language, related_name='user_native_language')
    likedobjects = models.ManyToManyField(LearningObject, related_name='liked_objects')
    savedobjects = models.ManyToManyField(LearningObject, related_name='saved_objects')
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

This can sometimes be tedious, but it helps to isolate the code from the built-in Django user models.

In order to ensure that the correct user is changing the profile, it should be as easy as checking the request.user and pulling in the profile for that user into a new form. A user should **only** be allowed access to a form or updating his/her own profile. You should never allow another user access to a form to update another's profile.

EDIT:
One benefit of adding a custom user model (e.g. "CustomUser") is the ability to add additional methods without messing with Django's user system. For example, I found this code yesterday, I can't remember who posted it:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, UserManager
class CustomUserManager(UserManager):
    def get_by_natural_key(self, username):
        return self.get(username__iexact=username)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    def add_email_address(self, request, new_email):
        # Add a new email address for the user, and send email confirmation.
        # Old email will remain the primary until the new one is confirmed.
        return EmailAddress.objects.add_email(request, self, new_email, confirm=True)
```

Adding this in lets my users change their email address, then await their confirmation by email before totally removing their old address.

Comment: Hey Jake,    Thanks for the timely response. So, you are saying that I didn't need to REMAKE the user class, I could of simply just added a custom user to the User class? Correct? Yeah I've been having the feeling that I did way too much work for what I needed... In what situation would it be appropriate to do what I did and make a user model?

Comment: Why do I need to make a 'customer user class' , why can't I simply make my class and connect to the User class by adding a 'user = models.OneToOneField(User)' inside my profile class?

Comment: Reza, you absolutely can do that. The only reason you might want to add the extra step of a CustomUser is in case you want to add other methods later on. Either way, i think it's best to have a separate Profile model.

Comment: Other methods such as what?  And what do import, abstractuser?

Comment: Yes, you would import AbstractUser from django.contrib.auth.models.  As for other methods...i'll edit my answer to include one.

Comment: Ok understood... So I am actually going to go with a simple extending the profile method, since this is simply just a project to show employers         is this the correct way to do this?   Keep in mind the value 'owner' is just to  compare with request.user later so I can control who can edit who's profiles.

Comment: class Profile(models.Model):

 user= models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
 about_me = models.TextField(default="")
 photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
 owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

Comment: You can go that way, but the owner field truly is redundant.  Django's authentication system makes it very easy to determine who is who. Anything you'd ever use "Profile.owner" for you can use "Profile.user" for. The user will ALWAYS be the owner, unless you set it up in a strange way to allow someone else to own a different user's profile.

Comment: so, at this point, is it really worth starting from scratch and changing my user models around given I've already done the work to create a custom user model from scratch? Or is not doing so going to give me more difficulties in the future ?

Comment: It depends on how far into your project you are. Django's user system is pretty amazing, but it does take a while to learn the ins and outs of it. I personally would not try to make my own from scratch. I'd worry that it would give me a lot of trouble down the road. Based on your use case, I don't think there is a good reason to build your own.  Then again, I don't know how much time you've put into it already.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, In your views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

User = get_user_model()
```

and remove the following (if exists):

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

Comment: Still got the same error,  and if I try owner= settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL I get 'django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: dating_app_profile.owner_id'